# Reading Sequence Diagram with some conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, uml, specifications, sequence-diagram

I have the following sequence diagram that consists of four lifelines exchanging a set of messages.

My question is:

How can i read the stuffs surrounded by red rectangle in this diagram?

[image]

This is My try:

The first one is:  "t=0"

as i understood it is a  Time observation but i really not sure because as i read through UML reference manual(2004) that the semantic of a time observation is get the current time and has a syntax "t=now" and here t assigned to zero?

the second is a condition "t<=500 ms"

Does this mean that this condition should be true to be able to invoke write(record) message?
and what about the condition above this message(t<=50 ms) what this means?

could you please clarify each one of them?

Answer (score 2):

first of all I am not sure that UML specification defines how to "read" your diagram.
Now the following is how I read it.
The first one "t=0" for me it specifies the time origin i.e. from this point the time starts.
Concerning the second ("t <= 500 ms") it is a constraint which represent the fact that write(record) message must be invoked at most 500 ms after the instant "t=0". It is a constraint of your modeled system and you do not know what happen if it is or is not invoked  after this 500 ms deadline because it **must not** be the case.
Hoping it helps.

Comment: would agree: provided you mean "...message must be invoked _at most_ 500ms after..." ?